# I have a class user with an id and name and I am trying to order a list of users with the name in reverse order first then by id in ascending order

Tags: python, sorting

I am wondering how I can order a list of users by their name in descending or reverse order and then by their id in ascending order. How would I be able to achieve this? I am trying to use the sorted functions but haven't been able to achieve this. I can only order them both in ascending or descending order.

```
class user:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

def sorts(users):
    users = sorted(users, key=lambda x: (x.name, x.id))

    for user in users:
       print(user.name, user.id)



user1 = user(41, 'John')
user2 = user(32, 'Doe')
user3 = user(93, 'Mary')
user4 = user(412, 'Andrew')
user5 = user(54, 'Jesus')
user6 = user(62, 'Abigale')
user7 = user(37, 'Waldo')
user8 = user(18, 'Abby')
user9 = user(92, 'Andy')
user10 = user(10, 'Hulk')
user11 = user(117, 'Ron')

users= [user1, user2, user3 , user4 ,user5 ,user6 ,user7 ,user8, user9, user10, user11]

sorts(users)
```

Comment: You need to use `users[:] =` to make users being changed in place.

Answer (score 0):

As you've alluded to, you can use the `reverse` keyword argument to reverse the direction of an entire sort. Having done that, you can negate the numeric key (`id`), thus producing a reverse of a reverse - which will just go back to ascending order:

```py
users = sorted(users, key=lambda x: (x.name, -x.id), reverse=True)
```